# Electrical conversion from European to USA

Tags: electrical

I am currently living in the US and have bought a house in Italy. I would like to take the many electrical devices i have so i do not have to re-buy them there. 
I have flat screen TV's, DVD's and kitchen appliances as well. Is there a way to convert or add US current with correct Hz so i can bring my appliances there to use?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a smart way to go at all, except for devices that only need a cord conversion (the inputs are already rated and labeled for 240V 50 HZ input as well as 120V 60 Hz.)

Some, but not all, TVs and DVDs might qualify. Virtually no kitchen appliances do, and you will waste a great deal of money trying to convert adequate power to run them. Save money on moving and not trying to tilt at windmills and sell them before you leave...

Comment: DVD players are interesting. DVDs have region coding so a DVD released in the US market will not play on a European DVD player and visa versa. You have to decide if you want to play your existing USA disks or new disks purchased in Europe.

Comment: TVs are also an issue. Back with SD, TV transmission used an entirely different system in the USA (NTSC) and Europe (PAL) - these were completely incompatible. With HDTV, from what I read, US HDTV sets will not receive European transmissions but European sets will receive both US and European sources. You may want to keep your US DVD player but you definitely want a new European TV.

Comment: If you travel with your dvd player, you might want to google to see if it can be made to behave as a region free player. (Some are very easy; others impossible.)